# Postgresql tables intersect

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a two tables in my postgresql database.
Both tables have same columns.

How can i prefer values from tableA which are not null?

```
TableA
id | name
1 | val_a_1
2 | val_a_2
3 | (null)

TableB
id | name
1 | (null)
2 | val_b_2
3 | val_b_3
```

Result which i want to get:

```
id | name
1 | val_a_1
2 | val_a_2
3 | val_b_3
```

For now I've got it like this, but its more complicated, because there are lots of columns.

```
SELECT *
CASE
WHEN TableA.name is NULL or  TableA.name = ''  
THEN (SELECT TableB.name FROM TableB where  TableB.id = 1)
ELSE TableA.name 
END 
AS name,
CASE
.
. another columns
.
END
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

why not use `COALESCE`? ***Assuming all recordID in tableA is present on Table2***

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        COALESCE(a.name, b.name) AS "Name"
FROM    TableA a
        INNER JOIN TableB b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
```

- [SQLFIddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/f4f66/5)
- [Conditional Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-conditional.html)

> The COALESCE function returns the first of its arguments (*there can be more arguments*) that is not null.

It's all about the `COALESCE`, not the join itself.

Comment: Well, we've got some complications here. Data we want to select are independent on each others and have nothing common / like ID in your case /. And also.. We've got about 25 columns, so do "coalesce(a.name, b.name) AS name" for every column would be stressful :) If you understand - I've got one unique row in tableA and one unique row in tableB, and these two selected rows i want to "coalesce". Like, coalesce, but between two selected rows. We've got with case when then but it's also very stressful, if you know what i mean :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a full outer join for the values which exist in tableA but not in tableB and vice versa:

```
select coalesce(tableA.ID, tableB.ID) as ID,
 coalesce(tableA.Name, tableB.Name) as Name
from tableA full outer join tableB on tableA.ID = tableB.ID
```